# XCode 8.3 - How many times can we deploy to an iOS Device with an expired Developer ID?

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-program

Good day everyone, I'm developing an iOS application and I was wondering how many times I can deploy to my iPad Mini (the device I use to test) without signing up for the iOS Development Program again. I had signed up before, but I don't have the cash right now to sign up again.

Does anyone know if there's a limit to how many times I can deploy to a device? I'm a bit uneasy because I might hit a restriction later on and it would stall my development process.

Thank you.

(If this belongs to StackOverflow instead, kindly let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/):

You can deploy to your personal devices as many times as you want; there's no restriction on deploys of this type.

You only have to pay the membership fee if you want to use the more advanced features such as TestFlight and the App Store.

Update:

- [Here's a list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1) of supported capabilities that require either a free account or paid one.
- The provisioning profile is only good for 7 days.  After that you need to generate a new one and deploy it to the device.
- Max number of connected devices is limited to 3.

Comment: So I'm good to go even if I end up deploying to around roughly 50 other devices? As long as I don't use any advanced features? Also, do they have a list of Advanced App Capabilities? Just so I know my limits.

Comment: The free program is not meant as a way to side-step the Apple Developer Program.  It's meant, primarily, as a way to help you learn to code and deploy to various devices.  As such, there are some limitations.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see. So that's a total of 3 devices at a time, anything more, I'd have to sign up for the Developer Program? How many times can I upload to a single device to test?